# How many paths through this "hexagon structure"?

Tags: combinatorics

How many paths are there from $x_0$ to $v_n$?:

[image: Hexagon structure]

I know its basically just counting, but I don't get it at the moment. Thank you.

edit: whoops I was in a rush sorry :D hexagon structure is what I wanted to write in the title.

Comment: Hi Peter and welcome to the site. You need to write more detailed questions. Also it is advisable to show some own work. Like what you've tried to solve it.

Comment: Hi mathreadler, thank you. I just don't know what else to write about it, cause the question itself is kind of minimalistic. And I wish I could add some own work, but I am just clueless at the moment.

Comment: I think the question is so minimalistic that many people don't understand it.

Comment: Well, it is all the information I have, it is a transcript from the exercise sheet. What else should I add?

Comment: What kind of math have you learned so far? It is difficult to know what kind of answer to give without some background.

Comment: The set $\{v_k\}$ is exactly the set of positive integers $b$ for which there exist integers $a$ such that $$a^2-3b^2=1$$

For more on this topic, see [Pell's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation).

Answer (score 1):

So here's a hint. Consider standing in $x_k$, $v_k$, $w_k$, how many roads can you pick from each of those. Maybe you could write it as an equation involving other $x$s $v$s or $w$s.

---

Ah what the heck, I'll show a way. But usually one is encouraged to show some effort before people will be willing to help.

So consider the matrix $$M = \left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1&1&0\\
1&1&1\\
0&1&1
\end{array}\right]$$

This is like an adjacency matrix in graph theory or something. First position is connected to two other, like $v_k$ is to $v_{k+1}$ and $x_{k+1}$, second row is $x_k$ connections and last row is $w_k$ connections. Ok?

The diagonal elements will be the number of ways. All we need to do is to calculate a matrix exponent with this M matrix and check it's diagonal elements.

so $\text{diag}(M^2) = \left[\begin{array}{c}4\\7\\4\end{array}\right]$ which you can count by hand that it is the same as going all possible ways from $v_2$ etc to $x_1$. Now to calculate this for higher powers we would like to move our matrix $M$ onto some canonical form. This could simplify the calculations a lot. We can find an eigendecomposition

$$M = VDV^{-1}, V = \left[\begin{array}{ccc}1/2&-\sqrt{1/2}&1/2\\-\sqrt{1/2}&0&\sqrt{1/2}\\1/2&\sqrt{1/2}&1/2\end{array}\right], D = \left[\begin{array}{ccc}1-\sqrt{2}&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1+\sqrt{2}\end{array}\right]$$

Now the rest should be an easy exercise to find an analytic expression for the number of ways.

Comment: You don't really need a $3\times 3$ matrix, because $v_k=w_k$.

Comment: So would a $M = \left[\begin{array}{cc}
1&1\\
2&1
\end{array}\right]$ do? Say the first index would be v (or) w and the second one would be x. I am probably too tired to get it right with a 2x2 matrix. But I am curious of how to do it.

Comment: Yeah, that was my point. The calculations should be easier for a $2\times 2$ matrix. Not that I have actually tried to perform them.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand how to do it. I would not be able to explain the concept as well with a 2x2 matrix. But thanks very much for the idea.